# prove that $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ and $|f^{(k)}(x)| \leq k!$ is $f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

I'm supposed to prove that $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ and $|f^{(k)}(x)| \leq k!$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x)=0$

My first thought was to use the Taylor series, but I was not given an analytic function, so maybe the series doesn't converge.

But I can still calculate $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + ...+ \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k + r_{k}(x) \Rightarrow f(x) = r_k(x)$

Then, I have $r_{k}(x) = \frac{1}{(k+1)!}f^{(k+1)}(\theta x)x^{(k+1)}$, for some $\theta \in (0,1)$

As $|f^k(x)| \leq k!$, so $|r_k(x)| = |\frac{1}{(k+1)!}f^{(k+1)}(\theta x)x^{(k+1)}| \leq |\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1)!}x^{(k+1)}| = |x^{k+1}|$

Then I don't know what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First, what can you say about $f$ on $(-1,1)$? Once you've answered, what happens if you replace your Taylor expansion at $0$ by a Taylor expansion at, say, $1/2$?

Comment: This problem was posted here recently but I cannot seem to find it

Comment: @thomine, your suggestion is similar to what nulluser has answered, correct? So I go from interval to interval until I cover $\mathbb{R}$, I imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x|<1$ then take $k \to \infty$ and you find that $f(x) = r_k(x) \to 0$, so $f(x) = 0$ in $B(0,1)$. Now shift $f$ so that some other point is at $0$. The same hypotheses hold and you find that $f$ must be zero in a ball of radius 1 around that point too. Repeatedly expand the region for which you know $f$ must be zero until you have covered all of $\mathbb{R}$.